# Publishing a Java library using JReleaser - maven.nexus2.mavenCentral.stagingRepository does not exist

Tags: kotlin, gradle, maven-central, jreleaser

I have the following config:

```
jreleaser {
    gitRootSearch = true
    signing {
        active.set(Active.ALWAYS)
        armored.set(true)
    }
    deploy {
        maven {
            nexus2 {
                create("mavenCentral") {
                    active.set(Active.ALWAYS)
                    url.set("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local")
                    snapshotUrl.set("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/")
                    closeRepository.set(true)
                    releaseRepository.set(true)
                    stagingRepository("target/staging-deploy")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':lib:jreleaserFullRelease'.
> maven.nexus2.mavenCentral.stagingRepository does not exist: target/staging-deploy
```

(There are barely any tutorials on this, especially for Gradle with Kotlin DSL. [I found only for Maven which was already helpful](https://maciejwalkowiak.com/blog/publish-java-library-maven-central/))

What is `stagingRepository` supposed to mean?
(I can also post the `publishing` part if needed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stagingRepository` is a local directory that contains artifacts to be deployed. Its use is explained at the official [guide](https://jreleaser.org/guide/latest/examples/maven/maven-central.html).

Comment: Searching by `stagingRepository` in that guide only leads me to code results (not to any explanation). Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: The guide states "Before continuing make sure that all artifacts to be deployed have been staged. Missing this step will make the deployment phase fail!" which points to https://jreleaser.org/guide/latest/examples/maven/staging-artifacts.html